# SSM model Standard errors Matlab covariance matrix

Tags: matlab, covariance, standard-error, covariance-matrix

Does anybody know please how to obtain standard errors of estimates parameter in SSM model matlab? or how to get them from covariance matrix?

Comment: Welcome to the site! The question seems too broad, and it's hard to understand as it is currently written. Please rephrase it into something more specific about programming. If the question is mostly theoretical, please consider asking at https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I’m still trying to figure out what a covariance matrix has to do with AWS Systems Manager.